# Array of 10 elements is sorting, but array of 100 is not

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a Knockout app with a computed property

```
  this.sortedItems = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.allItems().sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.name() > b.name();
    });
}, this);
```

I have a fiddle with this app with 10 array items http://jsfiddle.net/GSvnh/5925/ where everything is sorted in the beginning and also sorts when an items is changed - works as intended.

Then I have the exact same code, but with 100 items and nothing sorts there - neither it is sorted in the beginning neither it sorts when an item is changed http://jsfiddle.net/GSvnh/5926/

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sorting numbers return the difference since that is the right way to do it.

```
return self.allItems().sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.name() -b.name();
});
```

[Updated fiddle link.](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/GSvnh/5927/)

---

Check the following description taken from [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?v=example#Description) :

If compareFunction is supplied, the array elements are sorted according to the return value of the compare function. If a and b are two elements being compared, then:

- If compareFunction(a, b) is less than 0, sort a to an index lower than b, i.e. a comes first.
- If compareFunction(a, b) returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different elements. Note: the ECMAscript standard does not guarantee this behaviour, and thus not all browsers (e.g. Mozilla versions dating back to at least 2003) respect this.
- If compareFunction(a, b) is greater than 0, sort b to a lower index than a.
- compareFunction(a, b) must always return the same value when given a specific pair of elements a and b as its two arguments. If inconsistent results are returned then the sort order is undefined.